# encoding information in filenames (iPhone/mac)

Tags: iphone, ios, macos, encoding

I want to encode a short title in filenames.  The problem is that occasionally the title will contain a character such as a colon or a slash.  Is there a standard encoding that would be typical/appropriate for this?

EDIT: to clarify, I want to encode the title in such a way that the encoded title could be used as a filename.  Or is that called percent escaping?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you're asking for here, are you looking for a way to add slashes and colons in filenames?

Comment: Percent escaping is the way to go, and it should be common as the preferred way of accessing a files via NSFileManager is to use NSURLs rather than NSString paths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I do this is with a category on NSURL, which I use to get the NSURL for a filename in a particular directory. Once I have this NSURL, I can fetch or save the file using the URL after performing the usual checks about whether or not the file already exists and handling those cases accordingly.

The relevant code snippet is:

```
+ (NSURL *)adnURLForFileName:(NSString *)fileName inDirectory:(NSSearchPathDirectory)searchDirectory {
    NSString *percentEscapedFileName = [fileName stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];

    NSURL *URLForDirectory = [[fileManager URLsForDirectory:searchDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] objectAtIndex:0];

    return [NSURL URLWithString:percentEscapedFileName relativeToURL:URLForDirectory];
}
```

You can download the full category code from GitHub - [NSURL+ADNFileHelpers](https://gist.github.com/1657624)

Comment: And then use stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: to restore the title with NSUTF8StringEncoding. Thanks for the very useful tip.

Comment: No problem. I should really upload it to GitHub.

Comment: I've added a link to the extension, which is available as a Github Gist.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `-stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:` to replace the slash character with U+2044, the "solidus" aka "fraction slash". It looks like this: `⁄`

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solidus_(punctuation)

Comment: Is that what MacOSX does when using / in Finder?

Comment: No, it secretly replaces / with : ... there is some behind-the-scenes magic there. Classic Mac OS used : as a path separator and allowed / in filenames and OS X needed to preserve existing filenames, so it just swaps them.

Answer (score 0):

The slash is not allowed in the Unix APIs. The colon is not allowed in HFS and in the old File Manager APIs. The same filename character will show up as a colon in the former and as a slash in the latter. In practice: you can use the Finder to rename a file to "/" (because the Finder uses the traditional Mac separator of `:`), but it will show up as ":" if you use `ls`.

If you need to allow both colons and slashes, you need to encode the characters somehow. You could use URL-style escaping, but if you expect the user to look at the filename in the Finder or in some other program, it's going to look horrible. It's better to escape just the path separator. For example, if you're using the Unix style APIs (path separator `/`), you could encode `/` as `:-` and `:` as `::` (to avoid ambiguity). Or you could use some other little-used character for the escape.

Answer (score 0):

I have approached this problem by filtering the title before using it in the filename. `NSString` has some useful methods, such as `stringByStandardizingPath` and `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString`:. The filtering approach is lossy, in  that the original title information might not be restorable. Similarly, I don't think encoding would work because iOS allows such a wide range of characters in its filenames. One possible alternative solution could be a `plist` archive with *key=filename*, *value=title*.